# Отсортировать массив для пагинации php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть страница новостей,
Получается у меня стоит пагинация, я вывожу по 18 шт. на каждой странице

```
    0, 1, 2
    3, 4, 5
    6, 7, 8
    9, 10, 11
    12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17
```

Нужно мне достать из этого массива 0, 5, 6, 11, 12, 17

я пробовал через цикл for выбирать по 6 штук первый и последний элемент,
но так и не смог реализовать до конца

Comment: В каком смысле "достать"? Что вы уже пробовали сделать для решения проблемы и что именно не получилось?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev поправил

Comment: Ну и логику получения ID неплохо было бы формализовать в явном виде

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить переменную "пропущено страниц". В цикле:
 1. Если эта переменная меньше нужного значения (4?) то пропускать
    вывод, добавлять к переменной 1.
 2. Если эта переменная >=4 то обнулять переменную, выводить на экран страницу.
Надеюсь понятно, нет возможности сейчас накидать код...

Comment: Спасибо друг!
Помог

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал следующим образом:

```
$newArray = [];
$array = [
    0, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5,
    6, 7, 8,
    9, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17,
];
$iter= new ArrayIterator($array);
$seek = 0;
$count = $iter->count();
$id = $iter->current();
$newArray[] = $id;
$seek += 5;
do
{
    $iter->seek($seek);
    $id = $iter->current();
    $newArray[] = $id;
    $seek += 1;
    if($seek >= $count)
    {
        break;
    }
    $iter->seek($seek);
    $id = $iter->current();
    $newArray[] = $id;
    $seek += 5;
}while($seek < $count);
var_dump($newArray);
```

**Упрощенный пример:**

```
$newArray = [];
$array = [
    0, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5,
    6, 7, 8,
    9, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17,
];

$count = count($array);
$seek = 0;
if(isset($array[$seek]))
{
    $newArray[] = $array[$seek];
}
while($seek < $count)
{
    $seek += 5;
    if(isset($array[$seek]))
    {
        $newArray[] = $array[$seek];
    }

    $seek += 1;
    if(isset($array[$seek]))
    {
        $newArray[] = $array[$seek];
    }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: А ещё сильней переусложнить можно? Интересен практический предел...

Comment: Ну тогда напиши супер оптимизированный пример ты. Вообщем - это лишь пример решения, а не "идеальный" вариант решения... Добавил в комментарий вариант без использования итератора. Так лучше?